# C#, working with files, "Unauthorized Access"?

Tags: c#, windows, file-permissions

I'm learning about opening and saving files with C# and it seems that vista won't let my program save to a file on the root of C:\ , unless I run it in administrator mode.

Any ideas how to allow my program to play around with whatever files it wants?

Thanks!

```
private string name;

private void open_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        name = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(name);
        textBox2.Text = name;
    }
}

private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.WriteAllText(name, textBox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you already found the way... run it with the correct privileges.

Comment: Or better yet, play around in a space where you already have privileges, like your documents directory or a usb thumb drive or something of the like.

Comment: well yes, but other programs don't need to by ran in administrator mode and can easily work with every files on your system. for example, in Word you can save a file where every you'd like.

Comment: @Rob: That is because word is running with elevated privileges by default. This is the most simple case for the regular home user, but you can't expect this behavior everywhere. In many large corporations, for example, Word will run with only your use credentials and you'd only be able to write files to directories you own.

Comment: >>> That is because word is running with elevated privileges by default.
ok, can I give my program this privileges by default?

Comment: Even word or any other application is not allowed to save your files in the protected directories. Only way is to elevate your process as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make your program start with administrator rights, you have to change the manifest. This can be done by Add New Item -> General -> Application Manifest File. Open the manifest and set "requestedExecutionLevel" to "requireAdministrator". When this is done, open the project settings and on the 'Application' tab choose your new manifest.

Comment: Whilst this is the correct answer on how to actually resolve the issue. You should avoid requiring Administrative rights to run your application if you intend to deploy your application to users in corporate, educational, government, or military environments as many environments do not permit users to have local administrative rights.

Answer (score 4):

The program will run with your credentials, by default.

So, these do not have the right permissions to write to the root folder.

If you want it to run with other credentials you can us the [`runas`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runas) command line to execute the application with other credentials.

Alternatively, grant more permissions to the account the application runs as.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons for the UnauthorizedAccess Exception. Check one of those:

- path specified a file that is read-only.
- This operation is not supported on the current platform.
- path specified a directory.

I accidently hit the third problem today ;-)